# Erro no meu fgets não consigo adicionar dados nele

Tags: c

Estou com uma *struct* para receber dados em `char` e `float`, mas quando vou inserir dados no primeiro `char` com `fgets` ele não deixa eu digitar e já pula para meu segundo `fgets`

```
int ex22()
{
     struct cadastro
     {
         char nome[50];
         char disciplina[30];
         float nota_1;
         float nota_2;
     };
     struct cadastro aluno;

//Nesse primeiro fgets eu não consigo inserir o nome do aluno, ele já pula para disciplina

     printf("\nNome do aluno: ");
     fflush(stdin);
     fgets(aluno.nome,50,stdin);
     
     printf("\nDisciplina: ");
     fflush(stdin);
     fgets(aluno.disciplina, 30, stdin);

     printf("\ndigite nota1: ");
     scanf("%f", &aluno.nota_1);

     printf("\nDigite nota2: ");
     scanf("%f", &aluno.nota_2);
    
     printf("\n----------------Aluno cadastrado---------------\n\n\n");

     printf("\nNome: %s\n", aluno.nome);
     printf("\ndisciplina: %s\n", aluno.disciplina);
     printf("\nnota_1: %.1f\n", aluno.nota_1);
     printf("\nnota_2: %.1f\n", aluno.nota_2);

     system("pause");
     return (0);
 }
```

Comment: Tem certeza que é mesmo `c#`?

Answer (score 0):

Rodei esse seu mesmo código aqui, e deu certo, a unica diferença, foi que eu tirei o system("pause"). Verifique os arquivos de cabeçalho, se a main ta bem formatada. Tambem pode ser o compilador, eu usei o gcc aqui. Qualquer coisa comente esse primeiro fflush e/ou esse segundo tambem.